# filtering with combobox wpf ef

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, combobox

I am trying to search the table Station using multiple comboboxes, that are binded to the station collection and every combobox contains differrent "column name" from station, like: station.street, station.city etc. Here are my code samples:
XAML:

```
<ComboBox Margin="0, 5" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding StationCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="city"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Order_City, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedValuePath="city" 
    IsEditable="True"/>

<ComboBox Margin="0, 5" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding StationCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="street" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Order_Street, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedValuePath="street"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public string Order_Street
 {
      get { return _order_street; }
      set
      {
          _order_street = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Order_Street");
          GetStations();
      }
  }

  public string Order_City
  {
      get { return _order_city; }
      set
      {
          _order_city = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Order_City");
          GetStations();
      }
   }

    private void GetStations()
    {
        using (var entities = new MobilekEntities())
        {
            var stationList = entities.Stations.AsEnumerable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_order_city))
            {
                stationList = stationList.Where(s => s.city.StartsWith(_order_city));
            } 

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_order_street))
            {
                stationList = stationList.Where(s => s.street.StartsWith(_order_street));
            } 

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_order_streetNumber))
            {
                stationList = stationList.Where(s => s.street.StartsWith(_order_streetNumber));
            }

            StationCollection = ToObservableCollectioncs.ToObservableCollection<Station>(stationList);
        }
    }
```

So it works nicely. It takes all Station and writes them into comboboxes, and when i choose a city, the streets only from that city are listed in streetCombobox.
However when i want to change a city, there is only my chosen one. I made my comboboxes editable, so i wanted to backspace some letters, and then the list would be updated. Eg: I chose San Francisco, and when i backspace to San, there will San Jose appear in the list. Do u have any suggestion how to make it?

```
    public ObservableCollection<Station> StationCollection
    {
        get { return _stationCollection; }
        set { _stationCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("StationCollection"); }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your StationCollection property ?

Comment: You ment the thing i've just added (public ObservableCollection..)? Or u mean how Station is in database written?